# Why does IE9 distort my site (developed in IE8)

Tags: css, xhtml

I have 775 line of handwritten CSS code that essentially draws squares.  I don't know which part to post but here is the before and after of the IE9 (IE8 comp view) effect.

Please let me know and I can post any of the relevant XHTML / CSS code.  Previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905922/ie9-exibits-4px-offset-compared-to-ie8) for similar issue and post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968684/where-can-get-information-on-browser-version-changes) trying to understand if Microsoft publishes the parser differences.

Before (working)

[image]

After(broken)(IE8 comp view) - Account Menu moved and invisible because it is white. All tab moved.  Buttons moved.

[image]

Comment: Now's the time to post the HTML and CSS, preferably on jsfiddle.net. :-)

Comment: IE9 doesn't work like IE8 which doesn't work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE6 and none of them work like any of the other far more modern browsers.

Comment: "developed in IE8" is likely the issue. Never develop in IE. Develop in a standards compliant browser, then fix for IE. IE 9 is much more standards compliant, so the odds are that there is probably some non-standard CSS in your IE8 version.

Comment: XHTML you specefy the standard/doctype you want to validate for and can validate your code using w3 tools. What about CSS? How do you specify "which" CSS you are running and how do you validate it?

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_uri+with_options But honestly, I don't think it will solve your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have both pretty different parser so you cant rely on anything where IE8 makes something correct IE9 makes it wrong and the other way around.